# Fail2ban won't ban IPs

Tags: fail2ban

I installed the Fail2ban on my Ubuntu 18 server with **etc/fail2ban/jail.loca**l file

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
port = 22
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/fail2ssh.log
maxretry = 2
```

after restart fail2ban service I can allways see attemts to login **auth.log**

```
Jul 26 14:43:24 vps249697 sshd[4383]: Received disconnect from 118.25.48.254 port 55848:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 26 14:43:24 vps249697 sshd[4383]: Disconnected from invalid user radik 118.25.48.254 port 55848 [preauth]
Jul 26 14:43:49 vps249697 sshd[4379]: Connection reset by invalid user adm 91.236.116.89 port 28767 [preauth]
Jul 26 14:43:50 vps249697 sshd[4385]: Invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 38386
Jul 26 14:43:50 vps249697 sshd[4385]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:43:50 vps249697 sshd[4385]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.236.$
Jul 26 14:43:53 vps249697 sshd[4385]: Failed password for invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 38386 ssh2
Jul 26 14:43:53 vps249697 sshd[4385]: Failed password for invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 38386 ssh2
Jul 26 14:43:53 vps249697 sshd[4385]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:43:55 vps249697 sshd[4385]: Failed password for invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 38386 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:17 vps249697 sshd[4387]: Invalid user tomcat from 153.126.159.208 port 50732
Jul 26 14:44:17 vps249697 sshd[4387]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:44:17 vps249697 sshd[4387]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=153.126$
Jul 26 14:44:18 vps249697 sshd[4389]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=187.12.$
Jul 26 14:44:19 vps249697 sshd[4387]: Failed password for invalid user tomcat from 153.126.159.208 port 50732 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:19 vps249697 sshd[4387]: Received disconnect from 153.126.159.208 port 50732:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:19 vps249697 sshd[4387]: Disconnected from invalid user tomcat 153.126.159.208 port 50732 [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:20 vps249697 sshd[4391]: Invalid user user from 173.212.232.230 port 34124
Jul 26 14:44:20 vps249697 sshd[4391]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:44:20 vps249697 sshd[4391]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=173.212$
Jul 26 14:44:20 vps249697 sshd[4389]: Failed password for root from 187.12.167.85 port 33518 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:21 vps249697 sshd[4389]: Received disconnect from 187.12.167.85 port 33518:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:21 vps249697 sshd[4389]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 187.12.167.85 port 33518 [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:22 vps249697 sshd[4391]: Failed password for invalid user user from 173.212.232.230 port 34124 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:22 vps249697 sshd[4391]: Received disconnect from 173.212.232.230 port 34124:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:22 vps249697 sshd[4391]: Disconnected from invalid user user 173.212.232.230 port 34124 [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:27 vps249697 sshd[4385]: Connection reset by invalid user adm 91.236.116.89 port 38386 [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:27 vps249697 sshd[4385]: PAM 1 more authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.236.116.89
Jul 26 14:44:28 vps249697 sshd[4394]: Invalid user scan from 103.99.113.35 port 57228
Jul 26 14:44:28 vps249697 sshd[4394]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:44:28 vps249697 sshd[4394]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.99.$
Jul 26 14:44:28 vps249697 sshd[4397]: Invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 48694
Jul 26 14:44:28 vps249697 sshd[4397]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:44:28 vps249697 sshd[4397]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.236.$
Jul 26 14:44:29 vps249697 sshd[4394]: Failed password for invalid user scan from 103.99.113.35 port 57228 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:29 vps249697 sshd[4394]: Received disconnect from 103.99.113.35 port 57228:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:29 vps249697 sshd[4394]: Disconnected from invalid user scan 103.99.113.35 port 57228 [preauth]
Jul 26 14:44:30 vps249697 sshd[4397]: Failed password for invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 48694 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:30 vps249697 sshd[4397]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:44:32 vps249697 sshd[4397]: Failed password for invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 48694 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:47 vps249697 sshd[4397]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:44:49 vps249697 sshd[4397]: Failed password for invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 48694 ssh2
Jul 26 14:44:49 vps249697 sshd[4397]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 26 14:44:51 vps249697 sshd[4397]: Failed password for invalid user adm from 91.236.116.89 port 48694 ssh2
```

How to ban these ips?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
logpath = /var/log/fail2ssh.log
```

The [Jail Option](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Jail_Options) `logpath` defines the

> Path to the log file which is provided to the filter

If the attempts appears in the `auth.log`, that should be defined in your `logpath`, instead of this `fail2ssh.log`.

Additional hint: `maxretry = 2` is extremely low and will probably ban legitimate users, including yourself. Whitelisting your own IP address might be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the ssh port from 22 to my custom and fór now there are no attempts for login. I Also changed the logpath

Comment: It's possible to check whether the filter regular expression works in general by using `fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf -v` (`fail2ban <log-file> <filter-file>`)